# Primefaces DataTable with Null Value and Error in Filtering

Tags: primefaces

I'm new to primefaces. I'm trying to build a datatable with Filtering capability.I followed the configurations using the link below.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

When I try to set null values in the table, the filtering is not working or that row is removed from the view.

Can we have null values in datatable. If so how to handle Filtering?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]